# Use a proof by contradiction that for any A⊆Σ*, the concatenation A∅ = ∅.

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I want to know how to prove with contradiction that for any A is a subset of a finite set, then the concatenation of A∅ = ∅.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Suppose that $x\in A\varnothing$. Then by definition there are $y\in A$ and $z\in\varnothing$ such that $x=yz$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I am still having a hard time wrapping my head around it.